# Spring data jpa, how to write custom query for inserting multiple records in same table?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Following is my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE Animals (

     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

In mysql I can directly insert multiple records in one insert sql query. Like following.

```
INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
```

However, how can I achieve the same thing in spring data jpa.

Right now I am using CrudRepository's  Iterable save(Iterable entities); and I am eneded up with 6 insert statements

```
insert into Animals (name) values (?)

insert into Animals (name) values (?)

insert into Animals (name) values (?)

insert into Animals (name) values (?)

insert into Animals (name) values (?)

insert into Animals (name) values (?)
```

How do I restrict to One insert query ? Any answer will be helpful regarding spring data jpa, hql or jpql .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using hibernate you need to tweak [a couple of settings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-jdbc-properties). You need to enable batching by putting a value in the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` property. However that might not cut it as depending on the number of different statements you also might need to order them to be able to batch them. For this you need to set the `hibernate.order_inserts` and `hibernate.order_updates` to `true`.

If you are using versions or timestamps to limit concurrent modification you might also need to enable `hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data`

So all in all you probably need to add something like this to your configuration or persistence.xml

```
properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "25");
properties.put("hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
properties.put("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", "true");
```

A blog post explaining a bit more can be found [here](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/).

However if you are using MySQL it might not even work (yet) as MySQL requires an additional setting on the datasource to enable the usage of the `addBatch` for JDBC. You need to set the `rewriteBatchedStatements` to `true` to enable this feature for MySQL. Depending on your datasource you can add this to the connection string or as a seperate property.